# How get rid of these applications

Tags: sound

I don't know what I installed but my applications menu is full of audio related apps that I don't need and can't get rid of...

[image]

I searched and searched but couldn't find these apps to delete them...
Can someone please help me???

---

thanks @vanadium for your answer...
I executed your line of code and got this as feedback

> /usr/share/applications/in.lsp_plug.lsp_plugins_mb_gate_ms.desktop:Name=Mid-Side
> Split Multiband Gate
> /usr/share/applications/in.lsp_plug.lsp_plugins_mb_expander_ms.desktop:Name=Mid-Side
> Split Multiband Expander
> /usr/share/applications/in.lsp_plug.lsp_plugins_sc_mb_expander_ms.desktop:Name=Mid-Side
> Split Multiband Sidechain Expander
> /usr/share/applications/in.lsp_plug.lsp_plugins_sc_mb_gate_ms.desktop:Name=Mid-Side
> Split Multiband Sidechain Gate
> /usr/share/applications/in.lsp_plug.lsp_plugins_mb_compressor_ms.desktop:Name=Mid-Side
> Split Multiband Compressor
> /usr/share/applications/in.lsp_plug.lsp_plugins_compressor_ms.desktop:Name=Mid-Side
> Split Stereo Compressor

So I opened the first one "in.lsp_plug.lsp_plugins_mb_gate_ms.desktop"
and I get this:

> [Desktop Entry] Version=1.0 Type=Application Name=Mid-Side Split
> Multiband Gate GenericName=Multiband Gate
> GenericName[ru]=Многополосный экспандер Comment=Performs multiband
> gating of stereo input signal in Mid-Side mode.
> Comment[ru]=Осуществляет многополосное гейтирование стереосигнала,
> центр и сторона обрабатываются индивидуально.
> Exec=lsp-plugins-mb-gate-ms Icon=lsp-plugins Terminal=false
> StartupNotify=false Keywords=audio;sound;jackd;lsp-plugins;

sudo apt purge lsp-plugins-mb-gate-ms results to: Unable to locate the package...

there all found in /usr/bin ... Is it safe just to delete them???
I'd rather purge the app that those files are associated with

Comment: That is exactly my point... I don't know???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If these are applications in your application menu, then these entries are associated with a `.desktop` launcher, a plain text file formatted in a specific way to instruct the operating system on how to launch applications.

Find one with the command:

```
find / -name '*.desktop' -exec grep -H "Name=Mid-Side Split" {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

Open one of the found files with a text editor. On the line `Exec=`, you will see the executable associated with the menu entry. That will allow you to identify the program.

In order to find out what package installed the executable, use

```
dpkg -S /path/to/executable
```

Once identified, you can remove the package.

Comment: Thanks alot @vanadium  ... problem solved...  You made me a happy man... :)